# How to get 2 dynamic iframe from group of iframes using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get second frame which is dynamically created from group of iframes using jquery

example

```
<div id="mytesting">
<iframe src="http://facebook.com"></iframe>
<iframe src="http://google.com"></iframe>
 <iframe src="http://spam.com"></iframe>
</div>
```

**From this i want `<iframe src="http://google.com"></iframe>` iframe in this iframe  src url  will change dynamically every time**

Comment: You really haven't explained your goals for this iframe. What exactly are you wanting to do and what have you tried? WHere's the code that creates these?

Comment: i want to get 2 iframe src from group of iframe and i will print the second iframe  src to another div.

Comment: well that's not very difficult with jQuery so what have you tried? Please post code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to use jQuery here:

```
console.log( document.getElementsByTagName( 'iframe' )[1].src );
document.getElementsByTagName( 'iframe' )[1].src = "http://google.com";
```

The jQuery equivalent would be like this, which is not necessarily clearer:

```
console.log( $($('iframe')[1]).attr( 'src' ) );
$($('iframe'][1]).attr( 'src', "http://google.com" );
```

Comment: Thanks I want exactly like this